# Update sql post on specific date "behind the scenes"?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php website with a news section and the posts are stored in an SQL database. Each post has an expiration date (i.e. 2016-03-01) and an active column that is set to true or false. Active = true shows post.

I want the active column to change from true to false on the expiration date so that the post is no longer visible on the page. I know how to do this with basic php but that requires an input from the website, i.e. a push of a button or the page to be loaded, for it to update.

Is there a way for the database (or php) to do this behind the scenes and update the post on that specific date?

Comment: what you are looking for is a cronjob - a script that is called repeatedly which does such tasks.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto While this is for Ubuntu, it's basically the same for every other distribution.

Comment: You are trying to solve a task that is not requried to be solved. You should _not_ try to change that flag, since that means handling with redundant information. Instead you should modify the query that fetches the articles to be shown such that it considers both: the flag itself _and_ whether the date has expired.

Comment: I looked into the link from @YUNOWORK but it seems a little overkill...

Comment: @arkascha, I know that there are other ways. I can easily filter with the sql syntax when I print the posts but I need the flag/active to change for other purposes as well.

Comment: @PoorCadaver Looks more complex than it actually is. It's the best and most elegant solution. In your case, you'd need the following line in the crontab: `00 00 * * * php var/www/path/to/your/script.php` This will run the script every day at midnight. Then oyu just need the logic in the script.php to set all the flags correctly.

Comment: It is redundant though. So this sounds like an immature data model then.

Comment: @YUNOWORK, That seems to be the solution, but I don't quite get how to set it up... How do I install Crontab on my website?

Comment: Usually, the crontab is already installed on every distribution. Do you have SSH access to your server though?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The tip from @YUNOWORK worked fine. My web hotel didn't have crontab installed but I am now testing a web service that does the same thing. Works really great!

I'm using www.cronless.com right now. It's free and does what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using MySQL server. If this is the case, you can use [events](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html). You can define events to execute queries every hour, minute, etc.

```
CREATE EVENT remove_expired_posts
  ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 1 DAY
  DO
    UPDATE posts SET active = 0 WHERE expiration_date <= NOW();
```

More generally though, you can avoid this and add an additional condition when selecting the posts to be shown:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE active = 1 AND expiration_date > NOW();
```